# Question not found

Tags: support

How can I found this question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864201/using-encryption-in-csharp

Only in Google webcache

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xAFX8z0g7uoJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/22864201/using-encryption-in-csharp+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

And

http://www.cybertechquestions.com/convert-from-java-to-csharp-issue_313369.html

http://www.unlimitedtricks.com/using-encryption-in-csharp/

Include text (source code C# has any errors)

Please help me to convert this java code to csharp
 the problem is when convert to byte into csharp the result is unsigned byte but in java the result is signed byte and the class AesCryptoServiceProvider get an array of byte

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class WhatsAppDecrypt5 {

  private static final byte[] INITIALIZATION_VECTOR =
hexStringToByteArray("1e39f369e90db33aa73b442bbbb6b0b9");
  private static final byte[] ENCRYPTION_KEY =
hexStringToByteArray("8d4b155cc9ff81e5cbf6fa7819366a3ec621a656416cd793");


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    decrypt(new File("d:\msgstore-2014-04-03.1.db.crypt5"), new File("d:\tt.db"),
"has.cha.89@gmail.com");
  }


  private static void decrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile, String email) throws Exception {
    String emailMD5 = md5(email);
    byte[] emailMD5Bytes = hexStringToByteArray(emailMD5 + emailMD5);

    byte[] decryptionKey = Arrays.copyOf(ENCRYPTION_KEY, 24);
    for (int i = 0; i  24; i++) {
      decryptionKey[i] ^= emailMD5Bytes[i  0xF];
    }

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(decryptionKey, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(
      INITIALIZATION_VECTOR));
    CipherInputStream cIn = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile), cipher);
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int n;
    while ((n = cIn.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      fOut.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }

    cIn.close();
    fOut.close();
  }


  private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i  len; i += 2) {
      data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16)  4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1),
16));
    }
    return data;
  }


  private static String md5(String md5) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    m.reset();
    m.update(md5.getBytes());
    byte[] digest = m.digest();
    BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, digest);
    return bigInt.toString(16);
  }
}
```

In C#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace AESDec
{
    public class WhatsappDecrypt
    {
        static BinaryReader mIn;
        static BinaryWriter mOut;
        string emailAddress;
        byte[] Key = new byte[] { 141, 75, 21, 92, 201, 255, 129, 229, 203, 246, 250, 120, 25, 54,
106, 62, 198, 33, 166, 86, 65, 108, 215, 147 };
        byte[] IV = new byte[] { 0x1E, 0x39, 0xF3, 0x69, 0xE9, 0xD, 0xB3, 0x3A, 0xA7, 0x3B, 0x44,
0x2B, 0xBB, 0xB6, 0xB0, 0xB9 };
        public static void Main()
        {
            new WhatsappDecrypt("d:\msgstore-2014-04-03.1.db.crypt5", "d:\db.db",
"has.cha.89@gmail.com").Decrypt();

        }

        public WhatsappDecrypt(string inputFile, string outputFile, string emailAddress)
        {
            try
            {
                this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
                mIn = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
                if (File.Exists(outputFile))
                    File.Delete(outputFile);
                mOut = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.CreateNew,
FileAccess.Write));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }


        public void Decrypt()
        {
            CalculateDecryptKeyBasedOnEmailAccount();
            Decrypt(mIn.ReadBytes((int)mIn.BaseStream.Length));
        }

        private void CalculateDecryptKeyBasedOnEmailAccount()
        {
            String emailMD5 = CalculateMD5Hash(emailAddress);
            byte[] emailMD5Bytes = hexStringToByteArray(emailMD5 + emailMD5);

            byte[] decryptionKey = Key.Take(24).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i  24; i++)
            {
                decryptionKey[i] ^= emailMD5Bytes[i  0xF];
            }
            Key = decryptionKey;

        }
        private void Decrypt(byte[] cipherText)
        {
            // Check arguments. 
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length = 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length = 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length = 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

            // Declare the string used to hold 
            // the decrypted text. 
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an AesCryptoServiceProvider object 
            // with the specified key and IV. 
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption. 
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor,
CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream 
                            // and place them in a string.

                            mOut.Write(srDecrypt.ReadToEnd());

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            mOut.Flush();
            mOut.Close();

        }

        public byte[] hexStringToByteArray(string hex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                             .Where(x = x % 2 == 0)
                             .Select(x = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                             .ToArray();
        }
        public static string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
        {
            // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
            MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i  hash.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Article source: http://stackoverflow.c om/questions/22864201/using-encryption-in-csharp

Comments are closed.

Comment: I look in profile user.

I get

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869318/convert-from-java-to-csharp-issue

Comment: Can I ask why you care so much? You intended to answer it?

Comment: None found. All deleted :( Great http://www.unlimitedtricks.com/using-encryption-in-csharp/

Answer (score 3):

You can't unless you have 10k reputation; the author of that question self-deleted the post.

After deleting, the user reposted it as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869318/convert-from-java-to-csharp-issue; all that changed is one tag.